# Enabling solr highlighting on field

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to enable solr highlighting.  It works on certain fields but doesnt on others.

The solr documentation says something like   **A '*' can be used to match field globs, such as
'text_*' or even '*' to highlight on all fields where
highlighting is possible.**

I would like to know what decides whether a field is one where highlighting is possible

Comment: It can depend on the type of highlighter as well, but in general; the field needs to be a text field, the text needs to be stored and the tokens needs to have their offets assigned (through one of the methods chosen): https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/highlighting.html#schema-options-and-performance-considerations

Comment: @MatsLindh  this makes sense based on what I see. The field I am missing is of type String and it looks like that can not be highlighted

Comment: That's correct. There is no "part" of a string field that gets matched - a string field is effectively just a single token, so any matches in that field would include the whole field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @MatsLindh's comment above about the type of the field having to be "text", I found the matrix at https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/field-properties-by-use-case.html  to be helpful.
Basically a field should be indexed and stored for highlighting to be possible/